# How to store checkbox data for each user/row in datagridview so it can be consistant?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Basically, I need to store information about checkbox being checked or not for each row in `DataGridView` (each input, user). This information will be used later on for a query over the database.

Each row will have one of 3 checkboxes checked ( max. 2 per user, 1st/2nd and 3rd).

Datagridview looks like this:
[image: Datagridview with 3 checkboxes and users as row inputs.]

**My question is:**

How to store that data and how to save it so it can be consistent for every time I start a program for each user/row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you not have the checkboxes inside your DataGridView?. DataGridView allows you to have checkbox in your rows. It would be a much more better approach.

Once you have that it is simple, you save it to your database as boolean or bit datatypes. That way will be easy to bound to the checkbox value.

This article show you how you can work with that DataGridViewRow type: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-CheckBox-Column-to-DataGridView-in-Windows-Forms-application-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: If he want to use a framework, I have good experience with the xceed grid. http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/